# How to add extra custom social icons to page with same style?

Tags: themes, footer, social-sharing

I have been trying hard to add more social icons of same style as provided in the theme I purchased, but I couldn't understand how to do it.

The theme provides only limited social icons as shown in the footer of [My Website.](https://blockshub.org/)

How can I add extra social icons say like that of Telegram/Tumblr etc. but with the same style as is there for other icons.

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a hacky javascript way I've used before which is to use appendChild() to add a Font Awesome icon to the parent node. There will be a container for the icons, find its ID or class and save to a variable, add your icon html (or img tag) to a variable also, then use parent.appendChild(variableNameOfIcon); to add a new icon to the end of the list of children within that node.

You can also adjust the PHP template, either through use of child theme or there may also be a filter hook available depending on the theme to add new icons via filters.